# Magento 2.3.4 Custom Module Backend Admin fileUploader (MIME Type) Strict check is enable

Tags: custom, magento2.3.4, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I've created a custom module for MG2.2.2 and add file uploader the same as the product file uploader functionality.

I've now installed on 2.3.4 and there is an error when I load the form:

```
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Further look I've found out that the file: `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml` contains extra Key pair value in `data-mage-init`

which is `"isResizeEnabled": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getImageUploadConfigData()->getIsResizeEnabled() ?>`

When comparing with the 2.2.2 file it doesn't have it therefore removing it everything start working BUT I cannot remove from core files however I would like to work around it, does anyone knows or have faced this issue that can give some guide to a fix.?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, In case anyone stumble upon this issue. There are new DI in to be added in custom module E.G: `.../app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php`

That on new version was added: they are:

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\DataProviders\ImageUploadConfig as ImageUploadConfigDataProvider;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
```

Once I've added all the necessary changes for new version everything works fine! Done! problem solved!